# CamelCase или _

Tags: best-practice

CamelCase или underscore.

Всем добрый день. Да, знаю, тема вопроса - холивар. Но очень давно хочу узнать общественное мнение по данному вопросу, а не чье-то субъективное в какой-нибудь статье.
В качестве ответа предлагаю пользоваться комментариями.

Так что удобнее, нагляднее и чем пользуетесь вы?
`CamelCase` или `replacement_space`

Comment: Обычно это называется [`snake_case`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Все эти рекомендации уже давным-давно сформированы и имеют под собой достаточно точные и веские обоснования, причем затрагивают практически все аспекты применения соответствующих нотаций - не просто везде CamelCase или underscore, а варьирование тех или иных способов именования в зависимости от контекста - применяется ли идентификатор к названию класса, интерфейса, метода, поля, свойства, константы, параметра, зависит также от области видимости и модификаторов (static, readonly) и тд. Также есть различные вариации в зависимости от языка, иногда довольно существенные. Вряд ли имеет смысл разводить какие-то споры на эту тему, поскольку

а) как уже говорил выше, все эти своды правил уже сформированы на все случаи жизни - просто бери и пользуйся

б) ваши личные предпочтения могут не совпадать с чужими, вне зависимости от их правильности

Comment: вот убеждаюсь, что люди используют чаще всего "только везде" и по личным предпочтениям один стиль. Лично я комбинирую, и получаю иногда вопрос, а почему у тебя в одном месте так, а в другом иначе (например имя класса/метода) и код внутри метода

Comment: то есть именуют CamelCase'ом и приватные переменные, и параметры функций и все такое прочее? Ну это в принципе ошибочно. Хотя, ошибка не смертельная, но в некоторых конторах за это можно немножко получить по ушам

Если вы пишете исключительно для себя, то вряд ли вас кто-то за это станет критиковать - пишите хоть ЗаБоРчЕгОм. В случае работы с кем-то и/или на кого-то наверняка придется принимать общие для всех условия.

Comment: >и получаю иногда вопрос, а почему у тебя в одном месте так, а в другом иначе 

важно, чтобы у вас были веские причины на пользование тем или иным стилем, более веские, чем "мне так хочется". Это, опять же повторю, в случае, если не вы единственный пользователь вашего кода

Comment: в одной конторе даже константы через CamelCase были, ну я как порядочный человек НАПИСАЛ_КАК_ПОЛОЖЕНО за что "получил по ушам" вот по этому и задал данный вопрос. Имена классов - безусловно CamelCase

Comment: >в одной конторе даже константы через CamelCase

я уже писал выше, что стиль именования может отличаться в зависимости от языка. О каком языке идет речь?

Comment: В данном примере php

Comment: насчет php не знаю, но есть ряд языков, в которых константы пишутся в UpperCamelCase. Хотя, вот сейчас специально погуглил по поводу php naming conventions, и судя по всему да, вы правы - UpperCamelCase для констант php ошибочен